# lftp: "FEAT negotiation" message when I try to sync a remote (no SSL) folder with a local folder

Tags: linux, debian, lftp

I want to sync a remote folder with a local folder using lftp.

When I installed the first time "lftp" and I created this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get username and password
USER=...        #Your username
PASS=...        #Your password
HOST="..."         #Keep just the address

echo Sync started ...

LCD="/var/www/myfolder/app"    #Your local directory
RCD="/app"                   #FTP server directory

lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $LCD
mirror --continue --reverse --delete --no-symlinks --exclude .gitkeep --exclude .gitignore --exclude .bower.json --verbose $LCD $RCD
bye
"
```

Everything worked like a charm.

After that, I tried to compile lftp with SSL support (I downloaded the source, compiled in a *deb* package and installed it) to sync to an SSL FTP server. I did not figure out, but I did not need any more, so I wanted to come back to the start situation.

Now, even if I remove lftp and I install it again without SSL, when I execute the script I get this message:

```
mkdir `/app' [FEAT negotiation...]
```

The command just goes in timeout (I saw it with the debug). How can I solve it?

Comment: Probably the server has a trouble doing mkdir of an already existing directory. What's in the debug output?

Comment: Just "Timeout ... "

Comment: Use "debug" command to see more information.

Comment: How can I use the "debug" command?

Comment: Just add it to the command list before mirror.

Comment: ERROR: Certificate verification: Not trusted
ERROR: Certificate verification: Expired
ERROR: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name ‘ip_address’
**** Certificate verification: Not trusted

Comment: These messages mean lftp is compiled with ssl. Try "set ssl:verify-certificate no"

Comment: I solved putting that line on my .lftprc file, but I would like to know how its possible to install lftp without ssl.

Answer (score 31):

I have faced the exact same problem. It was resolved by explicitly providing a protocol prefix **'sftp'** in the connection string. By default lftp uses 'ftp' as a protocol.

```
HOST="sftp://<hostname>" # <-- make sure that you have specified the protocol here

lftp <<EOF 
set ssl:verify-certificate no  
set sftp:auto-confirm yes
open $HOST -p $PORT -u $USER,$PASSWORD
mirror $RCD $LCD
EOF
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've turned FEAT features off, and it worked like a charm.
Just use this command before opening a connection:

```
set ftp:use-feat false
```

Comment: `man lftp` (the man page) includes this tip on setting features in config files: ```On startup, lftp executes /etc/lftp.conf and then ~/.lftprc and ~/.lftp/rc (or ~/.config/lftp/rc if ~/.lftp does not exist).  You can place aliases and `set' commands there. Some people prefer to see  full  protocol  debug, use `debug' to turn the debug on. Use `debug 3' to see only greeting messages and error messages.```

Comment: What are "FEAT features"? Can you extend your answer (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?